# php is reading extra white space from html form select

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that I am parsing over with a PHP script.  One portion of this is a select box, that is populated from a text document.  When I select the option from the box, and echo it out, there seems to be an extra white space that I can not remove.  I have looked at rtrim to remove it but it does not work.

Text Document:

```
Family
Buildings
Paul
```

These were all placed into the document by a script that read input from the user on another form:

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input name="album" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="add" >
        <input type="button" value="close" onclick="window.close()">
    </form>
<?php
    $file = 'displays.txt';
    $display = $_POST['album'];
    $results = file_put_contents($file, $display . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

I realize that I use a newline for the files.  That is so that it will correctly populate my form selection.

Selection in form

```
<?php
    $file = 'displays.txt';
    $contents = file($file);
    foreach($contents as $line) {
        echo'<option value="' . $line . '">' .$line . '</option>';
    }
?>
```

The following is the code that reads the option input

```
$album = rtrim($_POST['album'] . '.txt',"\n");
$pics = array($album);
```

I am adding the ".txt" on afterwards, so that when I send to a python script, I can use it to make a new text document based on their selection.  When I run the everything I get the following for an output:

```
Array ( [0] => Carlson .txt [1] => IMG_2417.JPG [2] => IMG_3120.JPG )
```

Its the space between Carlson & ".txt", that is throwing me off.  At first I thought I was putting an extra space in as others have done, but when reviewing closley, I do not see any extra space. The next step in the process is to send it over to a python script using shell_exec(), would it just be easier to send the value of "Carlson" over without the ".txt" and add it on the other side?

Comment: `$album = rtrim(trim($_POST['album']).'.txt',"\n");`

Comment: `$album = rtrim($_POST['album']).".txt\n");`

Comment: where and how exactly are you using that (unshown) `<select>`? all I see is `<option>` - question's unclear. Post your actual code and how you're using this "exactly". Plus, `onclick="window.close()"` suggests you're using JS somewhere or some popup box of sorts.

Comment: I have my thoughts as to what's really going on, but don't see "how" it's used.

Comment: Plus, why was this tagged as python? You've been given comments and an answer. If you're not going to respond to comments here, then take it up with the answer given below. However, you may have left the question only to return at a later date. I won't be here at that time. I wish you well with this, good luck.

Comment: The python tag was an accident.  I also kept the code out because, I didnt want to take up a lot of space, just keep it simple.  Next time I will post the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$album = rtrim($_POST['album']). '.txt';
```

Have you tried this solution? 
You want to remove whitespace from input (album), so you should use rtrim only on the value you get from the input (in this case,$_POST['album'] ). After its whitespace get removed then you added '.txt'.

i remove '\n' because i don't know what result you wanted. if '\n' must be added to the end of the value, then

```
$album = rtrim($_POST['album']). '.txt\n';
```

---

Edit my answer

thanks for the comment. No single quote for \n, so it should be

```
$album = rtrim($_POST['album']). ".txt\n";
```

Comment: `'.txt\n'` - a new line will not parse in single quotes

Comment: This answer did it for me, and once I saw it I understood my mistake.  I was using the rtrim() on everything including the ".txt".  When in reality I needed to trim the variable THEN add the ".txt".  Fred -ii- is also correct, i had to use a double quote to get it work correctly.